# Jquery UI in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i include jquery ui to be used in my system? I've already put the code in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And how can I include the date picker which I already downloaded from jqueryUI. Here is the code of the date picker :

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<div class="demo"><p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></div>
```

I got confused how to export the downloaded file to asp. Thank you.

Comment: You added the jQuery library to your page. Now you need to add the jQuery UI file as well.  You will need to add the jQuery UI css file to get the controls to render properly.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

Comment: Use a [better reference source](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) @bryanmac. There are a [lot of reasons](http://w3fools.com/) not to quote w3schools

Comment: Yes and one of the reason is, stackoverflow is a better reference... lol

Answer (score 1):

Did you also include the references to JQuery?

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/themename/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
```

See: [JQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started#Basic_overview%3a_using_jQuery_UI_on_a_web_page)

Comment: also make sure you add the files to your site or reference a CDN: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp